# R data frame columns from vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I must be missing something obvious here but for this:

```
> range(data$timestamp)
[1] "2015-06-29 09:32:43.000 UTC" "2015-07-03 15:50:35.986 UTC"
```

I want to do something like:

```
df <- data.frame(as.Date(range(data$timestamp)))
names(df) <- c('from', 'to')
```

and get a data frame with columns 'from' and 'to' without needing an extra variable only to index. Written as above `data.frame` converts the vector to two rows in a single-column data frame. I've tried various combinations of `cbind`, `matrix`, `t`, `list` and attempts at destructuring. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df <- as.data.frame(as.list(as.Date(range(data$timestamp))))
names(df) <- c('from', 'to')
```

This will work. `data.frame`s are really just special `list`s after all.

If you wanted a one-liner, you could use `setNames`. I've also found this type of thing much more readable now using `magrittr`:

```
data$timestamp %>% range %>% as.Date %>% as.list %>% as.data.frame %>% setNames(c("from", "to")
```

Alternatively, you could cast via a matrix:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(as.Date(range(data$timestamp)), ncol = 2))
names(df) <- c('from', 'to')
```

This will, however, strip the `class` (and other attributes) from the dates. If you instead set the dimensions of the vector using `dim<-`, then neither `print` nor `as.data.frame` will treat it as a matrix (because it still has the `class` `Date`).

To get round this, convert to Date after creating the data.frame:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(range(data$timestamp), ncol = 2))
df[] <- lapply(df, as.Date)
names(df) <- c('from', 'to')
```

Comment: As below, `matrix` seems to lose type information/formatting. Looks like I was using `list` instead of `as.list`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try :

```
range_timestamp <- c("2015-06-29 09:32:43.000 UTC", "2015-07-03 15:50:35.986 UTC")
df <- data.frame(from=as.Date(range_timestamp[1]), to=as.Date(range_timestamp)[2])
df
#        from         to
#1 2015-06-29 2015-07-03
```

Another option, using `data.table` and avoiding indexing:

```
require(data.table)
df <- `colnames<-`(data.frame(rbind(range_timestamp)), c("from","to"))
df <- setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, as.Date)]
df
         from         to
1: 2015-06-29 2015-07-03
```

Or, as mentionned by @akrun in the comment:

```
require(data.table)
df <- setnames(setDT(as.list(as.Date(range_timestamp))), c('from', 'to'))[]
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to pull out another variable only to index into it.

Comment: @SamBrightman I edited my answer with another option, using `data.table`

Comment: If you are using `data.table`  another variant is `setnames(setDT(as.list(as.Date(range_timestamp))), c('from', 'to'))[]`

Answer (score 1):

I was a few seconds too late with my suggestion. As I see, others have already answered. Anyway: here is an alternative that is similar to what you have attempted:

```
timestamp <-c("2015-06-29 09:32:43.000 UTC","2015-07-03 15:50:35.986 UTC")
df <- t(data.frame(as.Date(range(timestamp))))
colnames(df) <- c('from', 'to')
rownames(df) <- NULL
#> df
#     from         to          
#[1,] "2015-06-29" "2015-07-03"
```